# DocuSign IP addresses

Tags: docusignapi

The following pdf gives a list of IP addresses of DocuSign servers:

https://www.docusign.co.uk/sites/default/files/Post_API_Certification20130522.pdf

Based on the information in this document:

1) to call the REST API in a production environment we have to use the hostname www.docusign.net

2) this server has the IP 209.67.98.12

Can we rely on this ? I need to be sure that the server to call will be always www.docusign.net and I need to know its IP address to properly configure firewalls.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you have listed is accurate as long as your account resides on that instance in Production. Your question about the IP addresses is a good one - I believe the version of this document you are looking at is a bit stale. Please refer to this post (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Announcements/Additional-IP-Addresses-for-DocuSign-Service/td-p/29702) regarding the IP ranges of the DocuSign service.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.

What does it mean that there is a range of IP addresses?
Can I use any one of them?

Comment: Hi Marco - there is a range of IP's advertised for our service to ensure maximum availability. In the event of a service failover, www.docusign.net may resolve to a different IP behind the scenes, so you should account for these ranges to maximize your uptime as well (IMO).

Comment: Is there a way to split the IP ranges into production and non-production?