# Range of IP addresses for DocuSign in prod and demo

Tags: docusignapi

Ad described in the following link:

http://community.docusign.com/t5/Announcements/Additional-IP-Addresses-for-DocuSign-Service/td-p/29702

there are ranges of IP addresses that can be used to access DocuSign in production and in a development server.

I am wondering if it is possible to separate the IP addresses used for the production server from the one used for the demo server.

I already discussed this in another thread but nobody answered to the last question:

[DocuSign IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544303/docusign-ip-addresses)

Based on the answer on the thread above, the document:

https://www.docusign.co.uk/sites/default/files/Post_API_Certification20130522.pdf

is "stale". It seemed plausible to me given that the "Post API Certification" gives only one IP for production and the other gives a full range.

Now I am a bit confused. Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an old link that you have referenced in your question, DocuSign has since moved it's developer community to here (Stack Overflow) as you have found :)

This information can be found in the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center), look at the **Post Certification API Info** document listed in the Certification docs:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation

Comment: I have updated the message to reference another thread where I asked information on these IP addresses. 
Someone suggested that the link that you are linking is "stale".
He gave me the link to the other document. Was that answer wrong ?

If it was wrong, could you please reply on the other thread so I can choose your answer as the correct one?